# Windows 7 XP Mode: is it OK to change the hostname and join to a AD

Tags: windows-xp-mode

Is it OK to change the hostname of the virutal XP instance, is this going to break the "XP Mode" functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ok to change the name.

Note that you'll need to change the saved **logon credentials** if you want to login as another user (like a domain user). This is done in the Virtual PC settings dialog for the XP Mode machine.

I'd definitely recommend joining the XP Mode VM to the domain for managing it, making it compliant with your systems and whatnot. Most things managed on the host should be equally managed on the XP guest like:

- Configuration policies
- Anti-virus software and definition updates
- Firewall rules
- Patch management
- ...and so forth

Some issues with networking could occur depending on the host configuration, requiring some further changes of the VM network settings to get it to successfully talk to domain controllers.

Comment: I'm nearly there but now I can't login because i've removed the save credentials but forgot to add myself into Users (or Administrators) group on the VPC, can you remind me what the original username would have been?

Comment: Answering my own question: userid:XPMUser.  Works fine now. thanks.